# how to post multiple text input in php

Tags: php

I am trying to post multiple text input that is being append but i end up being able to post only one text input which is manually inserted into my source code

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
     <div class="filearray"><img src="" >
                                                          <br><input type="text" name="text[]" placeholder="write something">
                                                          <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="file">
                                                          <div class="close">&nbsp;&times;</div>
                                                       <label for="file" style="position:relative;bottom:40px;"><img src="mediaimages/francis.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"></label>
                                                          </div>
                                                          <input type="hidden" name="animationtype" id="animationtype">
                                                      </div><br><div class="clear"></div>
                                                     <div class="p_v_post">
                                                        <button id="ani_b" type="button">animate</button>
                                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="post">
                                                     </div>
                                                 </div>
```

so when user click a button more input text is added but when i post it i only end up posting the value of the first input above,then i try to add up to five text input manually then when i post them it work fine but i want to be able to post all appended input.

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ($_POST["text"] as $key => $value) {
       echo $value."<br>";
}
}?>

 $("body").on("change","#file",function(){

                $(".p_v_preview").show();

                 $ext_array = ["image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png","image/bmp","video/vob","video/avi","video/mp4"];
          //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            $name =  this.files[0].name;
            $size =  this.files[0].size;
            $type =  this.files[0].type;
               $ext = $name.replace(/^.*\./, "");

             if ($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "bmp" || $ext == "vob" || $ext == "avi" || $ext == "mp4") {
             //alert("allowed");
                   if($size < 10000000){
                        //alert("allowed");
                        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "bmp"){
                               $len = $(".append_pre_p_v img").length;
                               $length = $len/2;

                                    $(".append_pre_p_v").prepend('<div class="filearray"><img ><br><input type="text" name="" placeholder="write something"><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="file"><div class="close">&nbsp;&times;</div> <label for="file"><img src="mediaimages/francis.jpg" width="200px" height="200px"></label></div>');
                                     $len = $("#sliderleft_array img").length;
                              $length = $len + 1;

                             $("#sliderleft_array").append("<img id='img"+$length+"'>");
                            //alert( $("#sliderleft_array div").html());

                 var filereader = new FileReader();
             var img = $(this).siblings("img");
             filereader.onloadend = function(){
                  img.attr("src",this.result).css({"width":"200px","height":"175px"});
                  $("#img"+$length).attr("src",this.result);
             };
             filereader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

             $("#sliderleft_array img").click(function(){
                         $("#img1").slideUp("slow");
             })

             $(this).siblings("label").hide();
              $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").show();
            //'<div class="filearray"><img src=" " ><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file'+idnum+'"> <label for="file'+idnum+'"><img src="mediaimages/francis.jpg" width="150px" height="150px"></label></div>';
          $(".close").on("click",function(){
         $(this).parent("div").remove();

  });
```

Comment: Show us the full HTTP request POST body.

Comment: I think you want to use a "textarea"

Comment: Show your javascript

Comment: All the `input`s/`textarea`s need to be inside one `form`.

Comment: they are in one form

Comment: Where are the other inputs/textareas? `text[]` would imply you have other elements named `text`, is that true?

Comment: i used jquery client side script to append them so it can not show in my source code or i my wrong with that

Comment: The code you have here is mixing JS and PHP inline. It is kind of confusing, perhaps this is your issue? `$(".p_v_preview").show();` is jquery, `$ext_array = ["image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png","image/bmp","video/vob","video/avi","video/mp4"];` is PHP, `$name =  this.files[0].name;` is a mashing of PHP and JS, I think JS would be `var $name = ` or `var name = `.

Comment: ok thanks will fix that

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the sintaxis name="text[]" is deprecated, and thus not recomended (if supported at all)

If you insist in use this method anyway, try seting the posting method to GET instead of POST, You may find that $_POST["text"] is not and array (though could be easily converted via array function)
Best regards.